# Does boolean variable need synchronization while checking in the given example?

Tags: java, android, multithreading, synchronization, synchronized

I'm exploring [an example of a simple android game](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/development/+/master/samples/LunarLander/src/com/example/android/lunarlander/LunarView.java) and I have a question about its synchronization logic.

Given two fields:

```
private boolean mRun = false;
private final Object mRunLock = new Object();
```

Method `setRunning` in a worker thread class:

```
public void setRunning(boolean b) {
    synchronized (mRunLock) {
        mRun = b;
    }
}
```

And method `run` in the same class:

```
public void run() {
    while (mRun) {
        Canvas c = null;
        try {
            c = mSurfaceHolder.lockCanvas(null);
            synchronized (mSurfaceHolder) {
                if (mMode == STATE_RUNNING) updatePhysics();
                synchronized (mRunLock) {
                    if (mRun) doDraw(c);
                }
            }
        } finally {
            if (c != null) {
                mSurfaceHolder.unlockCanvasAndPost(c);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Is it correct to not synchronize `mRun` in the `while` statement? I think `setRunning` might potencially be called while `mRun` is being checked for `true`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think the code is correct.

You should probably do something like:

```
while (true) {
  synchronized (mRunLock) {
    if (mRun) break;
  }

  // ...
}
```

Without this, you don't have a guarantee that writing to `mRun` happens-before the read in the condition.

It will sort-of work without it, because you are reading `mRun` inside a synchronized block inside the loop; provided that read is executed, the value will be updated. But the value you read in the loop expression on the next iteration could be the same value as was read on the previous iteration in the `synchronized (mRunLock) { if (mRun) doDraw(c); }`.

Critically, it isn't guaranteed to read an up-to-date value on the initial iteration. If false is cached, the loop won't execute.

Making `mRun` volatile would be easier than using synchronization, though.

Answer (score 1):

You need to keep the 'synchronized' statements. If you don't (though note that android, which isn't really java, may not be adhering to the same memory model as actual java), then any thread is free to make a temporary clone for any field of any instance it wants, and synchronize any writes to the clone at some undefined later point in time with any other thread's clone.

To avoid the issues with these 'clones'*, you need to establish CBCA relationships ("comes before/comes after") - if the thread model ensures that line X in thread A definitely ran after line Y in thread B, then any field writes done by line Y will guaranteed be visible in line X.

In other words, with the synchronized statements, if the mRunLock lock in your run() method has to 'wait' for the setRunning method to finish running, you just established a CBCA relationship between the two, and it's crucial because that means the mRun write done by `setRunning` is now visible. If you didn't, it may be visible, it may not be, it depends on the chip in your phone and the phase of the moon.

Note that boolean writes are otherwise atomic. So it's not so much about any issues that would occur if you read whilst the field is being written (that is not a problem in itself if the field's type is decreed as being atomic, which all primitives other than double and long are), it's ensuring visibility of any changes.

In plain jane java you'd probably use an `AtomicBoolean` for this and avoid using any synchronized anything. Note also that nesting synchronized() on different locks (you lock on mSurfaceHolder, and then lock on mRunLock) can lead to deadlocks if any code does it 'in reverse' (locks on mRunLock first, then locks on mSurfaceHolder).

Are you running into any problems with this code, or just wondering 'is it correct'? If the latter: Yes, it is correct.

*) Whilst this clone thing sounds tedious and errorprone, the only alternative is that any field write by any thread is immediately visible by any other thread. That would slow everything waaaaay down; the VM has no idea which writes have the potential to be read soon by another thread, and if you know anything about modern CPU architecture, each core has its own cache that is orders of magnitude (100 to 1000 times!) faster than system memory. This alternative of 'all writes must always be visible everywhere' would pretty much mean that fields can never be in any caches ever. That'd be disastrous for performance. This memory model is therefore basically a necessary evil. There are languages that don't have it; they tend to be orders of magnitude slower than java.

Comment: Thanks for a detailed answer. So, if mRun is not volatile it may will never be changed for another thread because of only copy of it is actually being changed?

Comment: Are you sure it is correct? It looks like it is expected that the `lockCanvas` can fail; if that's the case, there is no action here to establish the happens-before between setting `mRun` and reading it in the while condition.

Comment: @user3514538 a JVM is not broken if it does that. It's also not broken if the change is instantly propagated to the other thread. Thus, any code that relies on some specific behaviour is buggy, even if on your particular machine it works every time.